# Can't access Laravel admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I'm new to the laravel framework. I bought a project and I installed it but when I try to login to the admin panel *localhost/admin/home* it redirects me to the first page. Why is this? Is the problem in the authentication?

The template is *adminLTE*.

This is routes.php:

```
   <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', function () {
       // $user = Auth::user();
       // if($user->id  == 2){
            return view('welcome');
       /* }else{
            echo "Site En cours de mise a jours .. Veuillez patienter quelques minutes";
            die();
        }*/


    });
    Route::post('/post_login', 'HomeController@post_login');
    Route::get('/admin/home', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('/contact', 'HomeController@contact');
}); 

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('/load_coup/{code}', 'HomeController@load_coup');
    Route::get('/get_coup_div/{code}', 'HomeController@get_coup_div');
    Route::get('/reset_coupon_div', 'HomeController@reset_coupon_div');
    Route::get('/validate_coup/{price}/{type}', 'HomeController@validate_coup');
    Route::get('/back', 'HomeController@back');
    Route::get('/save/{price}', 'HomeController@save');
    Route::get('/get_solde', 'HomeController@get_solde');
    Route::get('/bet_list', 'HomeController@bet_list');
    Route::get('/bet_list/{code}', 'HomeController@bet_details');
    Route::get('/coupon/{id}', 'HomeController@print_coupon');
    Route::get('/transaction/', 'HomeController@add_transaction');
    Route::post('/transaction/', 'HomeController@store_transaction');
    Route::get('/transaction_list/', 'HomeController@transaction_list');

    Route::get('/profile/', 'HomeController@profile');
    Route::post('/profile/', 'HomeController@edit_profile');

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Route::auth();
    Route::get('/users', 'AdminController@user');
    Route::get('/users/{id}', 'AdminController@edit_user');
    Route::post('/update_user/', 'AdminController@update_user');
    Route::post('/add_transaction/', 'AdminController@add_transaction');
    Route::get('/match', 'AdminController@match');
    //Route::post('/match', 'AdminController@match');
    Route::get('/coupon', 'AdminController@coupon');
    Route::get('/coupons/{id}', 'AdminController@edit_coupon');
});
```

Comment: The screenshots of code were removed- if you want to include code, then add it as formatted text (use the toolbar button for adding code or see [the help documentation about [formatting Code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting#help-post-body)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have `admin` or `correction` role. Because of that you are redirected to `/`.

Comment: can you help me please sir i u like i will send you the project

Comment: How have you created your first user (admin user) ?

Comment: in register page of  the project

Comment: There was no add role to user or anything? You need to contact that person from whom you have bought that project and ask how you can add role to first user

Comment: he blocked me +
i have tow tables in the database 
the one called roles
and the other role_user

Comment: lets manually create role `admin` in roles table and than add the `user_id` (your user ID) and `role_id` (newly created role ID) in `role_user` table

Comment: i have this colonnes   id // name // display_name // description //  created_at // updated_at

Comment: put name `admin` and display_name `Admin`

Comment: i did it but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Look at the post_login function in the HomeController there will be a return view or return redirect. You can change it to go to the view you wish.

Comment: Please explain to me sir

public function post_login(Request $request)
    {
        $auth = false;
        $credentials = $request->only('user_name', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->valide){
                $auth = true; // Success
            }else{
                Auth::logout();
            }

Comment: Are you trying to be re-directed to another page after log in? Or you are saying you cannot view/access the app and you are being redirected to the log in page?